# Do clerics have access to every spell of the level they can cast?

Tags: spells, cleric, dnd-next-playtest

The playtest notes are not clear in regard to clerics. It specifically states how many spells wizards can learn. So do I just assume that a cleric learns one spell per level or do they have access to every cleric spell of their acquired spell level?

Answer (score 23):

For cleric:

> You decide which cleric spells are available to you to cast. Whenever you complete a long rest, you prepare the list of cleric spells that you can cast of 1st level or higher, **choosing from the *list of spells available to all clerics*** (see the “Spells” document).

For wizard:

> You decide which mage spells are available to you to cast each day. After completing a long rest, you can prepare the list of mage spells that you will be able to cast in the coming day, **choosing from the spells of 1st level or higher *in your spellbook***.

Emphasis mine. There is nothing in the Cleric description saying your list of spells is limited in any way, so I don't think we should assume it is.

Comment: If we take into account that in DDN they try to go old school and that except for the 4th edition, cleric always had access to all spells made available to them from their god (Ex : God of live wouldn't allow Animate Undead).

I think it's a fair assumption

Comment: I haven't seen anything to the contrary thus far. Also Paladins have the same description and thus can choose any Paladin spell they want each "morning." (after a long rest is not automatically morning.)